# Getting proportion of two or more variables with one code

Tags: r, survey

I am analysing a complex survey data. I want to calculate the proportion of smoking among rural men and urban men and alcohol consumption. I used separate code like below. Is it possible to get the same result using one code for urban_rural and alcohol?

```
svyciprop(~smoking, subset(svs1, urban_rural =='rural'), method = "likelihood")
svyciprop(~smoking, subset(svs1, urban_rural =='urban'), method = "likelihood")
svyciprop(~smoking, subset(svs1, alcohol =='yes'), method = "likelihood")
svyciprop(~smoking, subset(svs1, alcohol =='no'), method = "likelihood")
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your dataset? You can read more about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to  a point, yes, you can use `svyby` to get the answers for each category of a variable

```
svyby(~smoking, ~urban_rural, design=svs1, svyciprop, method="likelihood", vartype="ci")
svyby(~smoking, ~alcohol, design=svs1, svyciprop, method="likelihood", vartype="ci")
```

There isn't any way to do this for a list of variables without some sort of explicit loop or mapping function.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. Is it possible to get Confidence Interval too?

Comment: You need `vartype="ci"` for `svyby` to return the confidence intervals